# Connection between node and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I need help to solve this problem

After refactering the code to resolve the callback hell and use promises

I have that message in the terminal: (after NPM start)

> (node:5312) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>
> Connected correctly to server
>
> Insert Document:
>
> [ { name: 'Vadonut',
>
> description: 'Test',
>
> _id: 5b9a880ac685ea14c035e05e } ]
>
> Found Documents:
>
> undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
>
> at dboper.insertDocument.then.then.then
>   (C:\Users\wael5\Desktop\coursera\node-mongo\index.js:29:59)
>
> at
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: if you can provide some sample code, that will be useful. `result`  may not exist in the scope where you are trying to access.

Answer (score -1):

It would have been more useful if you could share your code, but your error seems simple enough.
1) You need to pass second arg as `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` to MongoClient.connect()
2) At line `node-mongo\index.js:29`, you are trying to access `result` of undefined variable.